# Changing a environmental variable through a C program

Tags: c, variables, posix, environment

Anyone knows how can I change the Linux environmental variables through a C program? I dont want to change the environmental variables that are copied for the execution of that program. I want to be able to change its value from a C program and then when executing the command 'env' in linux I can see its value changed.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

> I dont want to change the environmental variables that are copied for
>   the execution of that program. I want to be able to change its value
>   from a C program and then when executing the command 'env' in linux I
>   can see its value changed

You can't. **You can only change the environment of your own process**. You have no way of ever touching the environment of the parent. Put another way, anything you do (setting / clearing environment variables, changing local directory, etc.) will be invisible for the parent process.

The standard clearly states:

> The setenv() function shall update or add a variable in the
>   environment **of the calling process**.

The only way to change the environment of the parent is to get it to do it himself.

Comment: But I saw this post here in stackovewflow a while ago:  
Use the System.Environment class.

The method System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ()

and

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()

will do the job for you.

I just dont know how to call these methods

Comment: @user1486033 you notice this is C, not Java?

Comment: btw how'bout `system("export VAR=value");`?

Comment: @H2CO3 I thought `system` is using a new process ? Unsure.

Comment: system("export VAR=value"); .... it only changes the copied env variables within that execution of the program

Comment: @cnicutar I think it does, but doesn't calling the shell directly affect global state?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, but you only get to call a *subshell*.

Answer (score 2):

See POSIX functions `setenv` and  `putenv`.

`setenv` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/setenv.html

`putenv` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/putenv.html

As POSIX says *The setenv() function is preferred over this function. (putenv)*

> I dont want to change the environmental variables that are copied for the execution of that program.

As @cnicutar put in his answer you can only change the environment variable for your current process and not for its parent process or another process.