# Is that possible to redefine the value of "~/" (HOME dir) in linux C program (no root authority)

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

Here is my code
test.c:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* newhome = getenv("HOME");
    strcat(newhome, "/myDir");
    setenv("HOME", newhome, 1);
    printf("ENV: %s\n", getenv("HOME"));
    printf("ARG: %s\n", argv[1]); 
    return 0;
}
```

The "HOME" env has been set as "/home/user/myDir" in this program. But when I compile and run my code with the "~/" arg, I get such output that the given "~/" arg is still resolved as the default "HOME" env value "/home/user", but not the new set value "/home/user/myDir":

```
$ cc test.c -o test
$ ./test ~/
ENV: /home/user/myDir
ARG: /home/user
$
```

So how should I modify my code to fetch the new set value of "HOME" if I give the arg "~/", such as this output:

```
$ ./test ~/
ENV: /home/user/myDir
ARG: /home/user/myDir
$ ./test ~/../
ENV: /home/user
ARG: /home/user
```

Comment: I suspect `~/` is expanded by bash and the C program never sees it.

Comment: a) `~/` is resolved by the shell before your program runs b) `newhome` is allocated for its value, not the longer string you put in it c) modified environment is visible from your prog and forked processes, not the caller

Comment: A similar question has already been asked: [Changing a environmental variable through a C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710029/changing-a-environmental-variable-through-a-c-program)

Comment: You have undefined behavior in that code. From [the getenv(3) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html): "As typically implemented, `getenv()` returns a pointer to a string within the environment list. The caller must take care ***not to modify*** this string" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18277177/694576 Same issue with `chdir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the arguments to your program are set when the program starts.

Second of all the tilde `~` is expanded by the shell, before it starts your program.

Comment: you're right, the shell resolves the path automatically before the start of my program. But is it possible that if I give an argument ~/, and printf this arg, the output result is just ~/ but not the value of $HOME env, I mean just output the original content what I gave in argument, but not the resolved path.

Comment: @Jason If you pass the argument withing quotes, like `"~/"` then the shell will not expand it.

Answer (score 4):

When you run your program, it will run as a separate process. Since each process has its own environment, the `setenv` call will change the `HOME` variable in that environment.

When the program exits, you return to the shell process, and its environment. In that environment, there have been no changes to `HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

Tilde expansion is performed by the shell before your app runs, so updating the environment variable will not effect the command-line arguments.